# How to change the URL of a WebView with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a WebView pointed to a page that is supposed to redirect to another page, but it doesn't do anything. JavaScript is enabled on the app's side.

```
location.href = location.origin + location.pathname + '?v=' + data;
```

Comment: Is it a hybrid app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a WebViewClient? WebView's default behavior (if you have no `WebViewClient`) is:

- If a navigation is renderer-initiated **with** "user gesture", create an `Intent` ([code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClient.java?l=218-248&rcl=89b2665274dd45001ebbbdc5bb63e109e6cf8b3e))
- If a navigation is renderer-initiated **without** "user gesture" (e.g., created by JavaScript), drop the navigation ([code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClient.java?l=208-211&rcl=89b2665274dd45001ebbbdc5bb63e109e6cf8b3e))
- If a navigation is renderer-initiated and goes to some sort of internal URL (e.g., `about:blank`), load it in the WebView ([code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClient.java?l=213-216&rcl=89b2665274dd45001ebbbdc5bb63e109e6cf8b3e))
- If a navigation is **browser**-initiated (e.g., `loadUrl()`), load it in the WebView

You can override this default behavior by setting a default-constructed `WebViewClient`:

```java
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

You can find more info on [this developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#HandlingNavigation).